# Styled components - easier way to access passed theme properties than ${props => props.theme...}

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I have a theme file:

```
const theme = {
  colors: {
    dark: "#212121",
    normal: "#9E9E9E",
    light: "#EEEEEE"
  },
  typography: {
    textSize: "14px",
    subtitleSize: "28px",
    titleSize: "56px"
  }
};

export default theme;
```

Which I am them passing into my App component:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <Provider {...this.props.stores}>
          <Router>
            <AppStyles className="app-container">
              <Header />
              <Main />
            </AppStyles>
          </Router>
        </Provider>
      </ThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

And then accessing in the nested components like this:

```
const HeaderStyles = s.div`
  .link-icon {
    font-size: ${props => props.theme.typography.subtitleSize};
  }
  .header-link > a {
    font-size: ${props => props.theme.typography.textSize};
    color: ${props => props.theme.colors.normal};
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  .header-link .active-link {
    color: ${props => props.theme.colors.dark};
  }
`;
```

Is there a shorter way than doing `${props => props.theme.typography.textSize}` every time to access the theme prop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Representing styles using a JS object is usually done to keep styles modular and scoped -- this allows you to import the object(s) into specific components and then pass the objects in using the 'style' attribute on dom elements.  Your use case seems to defeat this purpose.  If you want to use styles defined as JS objects, I would recommend avoiding the indirection in the code block above.  Alternatively, consider using CSS modules or straight up CSS.  Good luck!